# Server is unwilling to perform. LDAP in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, openldap

I get this error always

> Server is unwilling to perform

and my code is the next:

```
   echo "Checking ...";
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $passwd = $_POST["passwd"];
    $host              = 'myhost.co.uk'; 
    $port              = 389; 
    $dn                = 'uid='.$username.',cn=nssproxy,ou=users,dc=co,dc=uk';

   // conexion a ldap

    $conn = ldap_connect( "ldap://".$host.":389") ;

    ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    // match de usuario y password
    $bind = ldap_bind( $conn, $dn, $password );


    if ($bind){
        echo "OK";
    }
    else {
        echo "NO OK";
    }
    echo ldap_error($conn);
```

Why I have this error? I'm  always testing with any user, this script return same error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I searched Google for `Server is unwilling to perform`and the first result says:

> C.1.4. ldap_*: server is unwilling to perform
>
> slapd will return an unwilling to perform error if the backend holding the target entry does not support the given operation.
>
> The password backend is only willing to perform searches. It will return an unwilling to perform error for all other operations.
>
> The shell backend is configurable and may support a limited subset of operations. Check for other errors indicating a shortage of resources required by the directory server. i.e. you may have a full disk etc

[ldap_mod_replace() [function.ldap-mod-replace]: Modify: Server is unwilling to perform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763070/ldap-mod-replace-function-ldap-mod-replace-modify-server-is-unwilling-to-p) has some requirements as well

Comment: I just had a similar issue where LDAP through PHP, which was working just fine yesterday, all of a sudden stopped working today. The error I kept getting was "your browser doesn't have cookies enabled" (from MediaWiki), even though they were in deed enabled on my browser. I checked and realized my /var logical volume was 100% full. I cleared some space, restarted HTTPD, and everything was just fine.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is what I did... I misconfigured `/etc/ldap.conf`, and added `binddn` where I meant to put `rootbinddn`, and that caused this message.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error. Ldap on virtual machine on windows server 2019 on 10.0.0.14 IP.

I managed to connect and bind successfuly, but this error occurs when ldap_add().

My solution was to check $record array parameters that i want to save.

I this set of properties work for me:

```
$r = ldap_add($this->LdapConn, 'CN=user 3,'.$this->Branch, array(
        'cn'            => 'user 3',
        'name'          =>  'test',
        'sn'            => 'asd',
        'instanceType'  => '4',
        'objectCategory'=> 'CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=test-domain,DC=com',
        'mail'          => 'mai222222l@mail2.com',
        'objectclass'=>array(
            'top',
            'user',
            'person',
            'organizationalPerson'
        )
    ));
```

Note that ldap_add() second parameter is path (dn) to entry and this can cause problem.

Path(dn) must be current branch + entry

For me current branch was 'CN=Users,DC=test-domain,DC=com' and full path mean dn = "CN=user 3,CN=Users,DC=test-domain,DC=com"

Note that this first part cn=user 3 must be the same as in bellow array.

Answer (score 0):

My distinguish names (dc) was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will save somebody a few hours, so here are some more possible reasons:

1. You have suppressed the real error message of `@ldap_bind`. Then you realise that:
2. the real error is: `ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server`. Digging further you realise that:
3. when upgrading debian to bullseye, you need to install `libldap-common` package.